# What is the benefit of the relativistic effects (time dilation and length contraction)?

Tags: relativity

Can an observer ever experience the relativistic effects, or he just can observe them. For an observer these effects happens only on other objects that he observe, but can he realize if he is subjected to such effect and can he benefit of them or to be in contact with?
A benefit from the relativity THEORY is $E=mc^2$, but what can we benefit from effects that we can only observe but not to interact with?
I am talking here mainly from a mechanical point of view since in electromagnetism the charges can interact from distance and these effects can come into play.

Comment: Is ageing less rapidly a benefit?

Comment: @Farcher  Hi. May I ask a question: Can we really say that someone will be aging less rapidly without accelerations, that is only by moving with constant relativistic speed? Thank you.

Comment: But only other observer can deduce he is aging less rapidly, to him he is aging the same. There is one benefit in that sense, if he has someone to care about he can send him with the speed of light and to enjoy his youth.

Comment: For instance, the circulation of the electric field around a charge is not zero for an observer watching the charge moving, but what can he do about it, what's the benefit of that if he cannot interact with the charge?

Comment: What benefits are you thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the observed half-life of a muon, in our laboratory frame, we get about $2.2 \mu$s.  However, when the muons are created by cosmic ray interactions with the upper atmosphere, creating very high speed particles, we observe that the half-life is much greater.

This is one convenient result from time dilation.  This is discussed in detail, along with much more about cosmic and terrestrial muons, here: http://www2.fisica.unlp.edu.ar/~veiga/experiments.html

The muon was discovered in 1936, from cosmic ray studies.